# Does "Seton" have any particular meaning?

Tags: seton-academy

Does the name "Seton", of Seton Academy, have any particular meaning, particularly referring to wild animals? I tried looking up whether it was the name of a famous zoologist, or biologist, or taxonomist, or something similar, and came up blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely named after a wildlife illustrator/writer and naturalist named [Ernest Thompson Seton](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Ernest-Thompson-Seton). His animal stories works such as, *Wildlife I Know*, *Biography of the Gray Bear*, and *The Life of Hunted Things* are collectively referred to as "[Seton Animal Stories](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3%E5%8B%95%E7%89%A9%E8%A8%98)" in Japan.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wonder why I wasn't able to find it (probably because if he was just listed as "illustrator" in the list of Setons I was looking at, I would have ignored it).